# Two main() in C++ project won't build

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I recently downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express to try to learn C++ and I am running in to a problem. I have used Eclipse before with Java and Microsoft Visual C++ seems similar to it.

So my problem is that I create a project called Project and I have two files (HelloWorld.cpp and PowersOfTwo.cpp) in the project. The HelloWorld.cpp's code is below:

```
 /* 
Hello World File
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<< "Hello, World" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The PowersOfTwo.cpp code is below:

```
    /*
This program generates the powers of two
until the number that the user requested
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int raiseToPower(int n, int k);

int main()
{
    int limit;
    cout << "This program lists the powers of two. " << endl;
    cout << "Enter exponent limit: ";
    cin >> limit;

    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        cout << "2 to the " << i << " = " << raiseToPower(2, i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Function for raiseToPower */

int raiseToPower(int n, int k)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        result *= n;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Basically, I tried to start without debugging the PowersOfTwo.cpp file but I end up with a fatal error stating that _main is already defined in the HelloWorld.obj. Does that mean I cannot have two files with a main method in the same project (as opposed to eclipse when I could have two files with a main method). Does that also mean that I have to create a new project every time for an unrelated program to work?

Comment: Which `main` would be used to start the program?

Comment: Then remove the other one.

Comment: You can only have one main function. It's a rule.

Comment: So I just have to delete the HelloWorld.cpp file

Comment: Just right click it in the solution explorer and it should have a remove/delete option.

Comment: How come you can only have one main function in a project as opposed to eclipse?

Comment: Because Eclipse lets you set which file is used to start your program IIRC. All of the C++ files are compiled and linked, which means you end up with two main definitions.

Comment: @chris Eclipse let you set the start _project_ not _source file_. Each _project_ may (and will) have its own `main`. Same applies to Visual Studio.

Comment: Can I unlink the C++ from compiling together?

Comment: @harper, Eh, everything lets you do that. Maybe I was thinking of NetBeans.

Comment: Have a helloworld_main and powersoftwo_main functions and one main function which calls one of them depending on your fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Whereas any number of classes in Java can have a "main" function, only one "main" function may appear in a C++ program.

Comment: I noticed that under the HelloWorld.cpp file, there is the words Global Scope underneath it. Is it possible to change this to local scope to make it work?

Comment: No, what you are looking at is merely a source code browser that helps you find classes and objects.  It has nothing to do with projects and programs.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio for C++, a "project" is a "program."  Every time you want to make a new program, a new .exe file, you must create a new project.  You can't have a single project that you use to make multiple different programs with different C++ files.

A "solution" is a group of projects, and you can have many programs in a solution.  Create one solution for all your experiments, then add a new project every time you want to write a new program.